# dual booted with win 10 and ubuntu , but after shutdown it stuck on ubuntu logo

Tags: dual-boot

i have dual boot my system with windows 10 with ubuntu. And the problem is that while using ubuntu, when i am  going to shutdown it stuck on ubuntu logo boot.

Answer (score 0):

Removing obsolete packages using Synaptic package manager (`sudo apt install synaptic`) -> *Installed (local or obsolete)* in the left pane fixed it for me. Obsolete packages were causing Ubuntu to hang when shutting down. Removing obsolete packages permanently changed it from always hanging at shutdown to never hanging at shutdown.

Before you remove an obsolete package in Synaptic run the following command on the package name to check if any other packages that you have installed require it as a dependency.

```
apt-cache rdepends <package-name>
```

Replace `<package-name>` in the above command with the name of the package.